# How do parrots stabilize their field of view without moving their necks while walking?

Tags: vision, ornithology

Based on my search online, I have found some theories which try to validate the activity of some birds (like pigeons) which involves moving their heads and neck while walking. These theories include - Assistance with balance, Providing depth perception, Sharpening their vision. Also, most of the studies state that similar to our eye movement, they need to move their heads along with their eyes to stabilize their surroundings visually.
If the above mentioned hypothesis is true, then how do some birds which do not move their heads while walking, manage to visually stabilize their surroundings and balance themselves?

Comment: why can't you just Google your question ?

Comment: I googled it, and found some possible reasons as to why the birds have to bob their heads while walking, but I did not find any theories about why some don't do so. Also, I think that finding interesting answers and rational discussions here on Stack Exchange from real knowledgeable people here on Stack Exchange can be quite enlightening for some people  with much less effort online. So repeating the same answer (which is found online),maybe in more detail, if the question wants something more, which is not found easily, it should be answered. Even if you say so, I will modify the question.

Comment: You can include your research results or any details you want to share in order to get a clarified answer, but a question with only two sentences and without even mentioning what you know about this so far, can make everyone believe that it is a home work type. Re framing the question may help. In future please feel free to use our [Helpcentre](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Edited. Is it OK?

Comment: @a.aniq This question is still so broad. Tell me do you have an answer for why the gaits of different animals are different or why dogs wag their tails but monkeys do not?